# Replacing text in Visio but keep formatting

Tags: c#, vba, visio

How can I replace some text programmatically in Visio 2013 by a Macro or an C# addin?
I tried this:

```
Sub Replace_text()
For Each o In Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
o.Text = Replace(o.Text, "123", "234")
Next
End Sub
```

But the formatting is lost, i.e. before replace I have this

**aaa** ***123*** *bbb*

but after:

aaa 234 bbb

I do understand Text isn't the right property to use
I need something like "GetFormattedText" or "GetTextAsHtml" or "GetRichText".

Any suggestions?

*(Doing this non-programmaticaly, by Ctrl+H, is not an option...
I have many documents, and I need to replace many different strings at once and this is not a one-time task)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with this without having to do anything too crazy, because when a shape's text is partially formatted like that, Visio stores that formatting using character runs.

From what I learned while figuring this out myself, Visio seems to store the text in chunks of similar formatting called a Run, so each Run then has a Text value and set of character properties.

So in your case, if you can assume that the text you're finding (i.e. "123") will always have the same formatting, then you should be able to find the index of the string you're replacing (using InStr), then do something like this:

```
Dim Chars as Visio.Characters
Set Chars = o.Characters
Chars.Begin = instr( 1 , o.Text , "123" )
Chars.End = Chars.Begin + Len( "123" )
Chars.Text = "234"
```

If you can't assume the text you're replacing has the same formatting for that little chunk of text, then you'll have to first see if the shape text contains your string, and if it does you'll have to find the runs that encapsulate the text, then replace the text within those runs.